# In rails testing, create model only in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a model with polymorphic association that I am running rspecs on.
The tests require the polymorphic field to point to a model with some fields (e.g. name).

Since I prefer not to use any of my existing (and complex)models, I was thinking of somehow creating a new simple models (that will only exist in tests) that my main models can point to.

Is there a way to do this ? 
Any other way to test models when they are dependant on another models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - using the 'mocha' gem.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

In tests, can just do:

```
class MockUser {
# Stuff
}

comment = Comment.create!.expects('commentable').returns(MockUser.new)
```

Now it will simply work:

```
comment.commentable.name
```

Answer (score 0):

As you expect, tests should be independant.

This is where stubs and mocks appear and it's the Rails way to proceed.

If you want to create a module dedicated to tests (which is overkill cause it's the role of stubs), just remind ruby classes and modules are executable.

So you could simply do:

```
if Rails.env.test?

module Foo
...
end

end
```